# Use Trim on all records in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, trim

Is this possible in phpMyAdmin, to execute that query on all records within a table (to get rid of any whitespace)

Comment: What is wrong with an UPDATE statement?

Comment: Yes i can do that but i'm not sure how to construct it so it does every record??

Comment: If you just do an UPDATE without a WHERE clause, it should update every record.  Or do you want to update every field in every record?

Comment: yes every field unfortunately! Thats why i'm struggling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have to list the field name but you'd only need to do so once per field.

`UPDATE 'table_name' SET 'field_name' = TRIM('field_name')`

(I would advise testing this before running it on your live data)

Comment: hmmm error in SQL syntax - are you sure they're all supposed to be 'field_name'?

Comment: @user478144, you have to replace field_name with the name of your columns.

Comment: yeah i understood that bit, i mean do the 3 bits i sub in for "field_name" have to be the same? Ie this is my query: UPDATE `parts` SET description = TRIM(description) however this isnt working!?

Comment: @benhowdle89 this might constitute a hellbump since this is from over 5 years ago but if "not working" means you're getting an error about SQL safe updates being on, you need to run `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` before executing the query; depending on your configuration anything that sweeps a table with an update without being key-specific might throw an error if safe updates aren't disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Try to cheat:

```
update venues set postcode=TRIM(postcode)+''
```